# where would I post a specific question about a certain language syntax?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday I asked a question on 'Programmers' that created a bit of a stir:

[Why does this question exist twice? Stack Exchange Multiverse?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2606/why-does-this-question-exist-twice-stack-exchange-multiverse)

Today I have another question along similar lines.  It's a question regarding unusual syntax in a particular language.  Because Stackoverflow is about answering questions specific to problems in a users code base, I thought a general question about a language syntax would go to 'Programmers'.  Now I'm confused.  Can someone direct me to the proper place to post a question like this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choosing between Stack Overflow and Programmers Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82988/choosing-between-stack-overflow-and-programmers-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 1):

If the question is primarily conceptual, ask it on programmers.  If it's primarily about code, put it on SO.

Another way to look at it is: if the problem is best worked out on a *white-board,* put it on Programmers.  If the problem is best worked out in an *IDE*, ask it on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Well, is it a `a question regarding unusual syntax in a particular language` or is it `a general question about ... language syntax`?

In the first case, I'd say it should definitely go to SO.

In the second case, it sounds like it might be a subjective question, in which case it might not be a great fit for either SO or Programmers.  But if it's not too subjective, it sounds to me like a better fit for Programmers.

Comment: It's not subjective, it's very specific.  Sounds like Stackoverflow is the place to go.